# Trying to save and print a single sheet in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, export

I have been looking into an ongoing problem for my manager and I am stumped, He is trying to get it so when the end user clicks a macro assigned button on one of the Excel sheets, it saves a single sheet as PDF and prints the sheet too.

I have got the point shown by the image provided at the very bottom and the code runs up until the 'ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat' line. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should use in order to get the explained?

I would really appreciate it.

Here's the code that I have till now:

```
Public Sub SavePrint()
 ChDir "Path-to-the-file" 
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _ 
                                 "Path-to-the-file\ACT Form.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                 IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True 
End Sub
```

Regards, Kieran

Comment: Please copy/paste the code here instead of a pic to make it easier to reproduce your code.

Comment: I would change name of the file. Windows cannot have backslash in the name. also check this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907(v=office.12).aspx) for a little bit more insight.

Comment: Took the slashes out and it's still not running. Even visited the page you linked kindly so read through and I still don't have a solution myself.

Comment: If `path-to-the-file` is on a network drive, there may be some problems due to that.

Comment: It will be on a network drive. My manager planned to have a folder in an archive so we have electronic copies of the document.

Comment: Do you map the directory or use the explicit path, i.e `\\internal.example.com`?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @0m3r Sorry about the delayed response. The error I get is Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. Then when I choose debug, It highlights everything after the ChDir line down to OpenAfterPublish:=True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note1:** `ChDir` needs to be used appropriately; after that you changed the path, you don't need to include it in the `Filename` and Excel automatically save the file in the current directory.

**Note2:** You need PDF add-in to use `ExportAsFuxedFormat`. To make sure that you have it navigate to
`Excel > File > Options > Add-Ins > (at the bottom) Manage: COM Add-ins`
Then find `Adobe PDF` or any other application that you use for managing PDFs (e.g. `NitroPDF` or `BlueBeam`) and check the box. If you don't have `Adobe PDF` then you need to install it on your machine and activate it in excel (i.e. checking the box) prior to running this `macro`.

```
Public Sub SavePrint()
 ChDir "C:\"
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _ 
                             "ACT Form.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                             IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True 
End Sub
```

This will save the PDF file in `C:\` folder.

Read this [post](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/chdir.php) to learn more about `ChDir`.

Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238907(v=office.12).aspx) to get an insight about `ExportAsFixedFormat`.

You can find out how to add `Adobe PDF` to the excel [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/adobe-pdf-add-in-missing-from-excel-2013-office/57ec53ea-123e-4cd0-a2a8-9d1bc63ca82d).

Comment: The dashes instead of the file path was just for privacy reasons, it would normally have the entire file path to a folder on a network. Sorry, I didn't state that in the OP.

Comment: @KFarley I figure that out. The point is about the `Filename`. When you change the directory you don't need to include it in the name of the file. It works perfectly fine for me. Let me know what is the problem now.

Comment: @KFarley tell me what error do you get exactly right now. Number of the error would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. The error I get is Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. Then when I choose debug, It highlights everything after the ChDir line down to OpenAfterPublish:=True..

Comment: @KFarley try explicit coding. instead of ActiveSheet, use Worksheet("Sheet1"). I am gonna check it out again later today but it worked for me before.

Comment: @KFarley Do you have a PDF add-in? That error for me only happens on that occasion.

Comment: Oh god I am not very bright! Thanks Masoud for the support, that worked with the add-in, top man.

Comment: @KFarley You're Welcome. I quote this: "Don't forget to tip your waiter by clicking on the check mark next to the answer if that is useful." This will let everyone to find the answer to an already asked question.